# Catch the exception and assert it using C# Nunit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, nunit, assert

I am doing a negative test and I am expecting to get an exception. So all I want to know is how I can catch the exception's message and then assert it.

```
[Then(@"I create the (.*)")]
    public void ThenICreateTheContact(string entityName)
    {
        entityId = m_OrgServ.Create(entity);
    }

    [Then(@"I verify the exception")]
    public void ThenIVerifyTheException()
    {
        ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
    }
```

and this is the exception -

```
Generic Exception caught: contact With Id = 81b10448-49b2-ea11-aacb-067e3e789e92 Does Not ExistSystem.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Generic Exception caught: contact With Id = 81b10448-49b2-ea11-aacb-067e3e789e92 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details:
```

The exception occurs when I do m_OrgServ.Create(entity); 
So I want to catch it and then assert its message in the next method that I have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TestDelegate.

```
    private TestDelegate _create;
    
    [Then(@"I create the (.*)")]
    public void ThenICreateTheContact(string entityName)
    {
        _create = () => m_OrgServ.Create(entity);
    }

    [Then(@"I verify the exception")]
    public void ThenIVerifyTheException()
    {
      var exception = Assert.Throws<FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>>(_create);
      Assert.That(exception.Message, Is.EqualTo("expected message here"));
    }
```

Comment: seems like it worked but I am getting error in asserting now, I am getting -------------- Expected: <System.Exception>
  But was:  <System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Generic Exception caught: contact With Id = e1165b1b-64b2-ea11-aacb-067e3e789e92 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details: 
ErrorCode: 0x80040265
Message: Generic Exception caught: contact With Id = e1165b1b-64b2-ea11-aacb-067e3e789e92 Does Not Exist; 
[SparkUserInf... so on

Comment: You should Assert your specific Exception . For example : Assert.Throws<FaultException>(_create);

Comment: I am now getting Expected: <System.ServiceModel.FaultException>
          But was:  <System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Generic Exception caught: contact With Id = 8fa71760-63b4-ea11-aacc-067e3e789e92 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details: 
        ErrorCode: 0x80040265
        Message: Generic Exception caught: contact With Id..... So the exception I am getting is not <System.ServiceModel.FaultException> , it has more to it as I have shown before ... how can I get around this ?

Comment: Try this :             Assert.Throws<FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>>(_create);

Comment: Thanks Arsalan !! it works , however I can't use Assert.That(exception.Message, Is.EqualTo("expected message here")); as part of the message in the exception is dynamic ( Exception caught: contact With Id = e1165b1b-64b2-ea11-aacb-067e3e789e92 Does Not Exist -- the Id part is dynamic) . Is there anyway I can use a Contains instead of Is.EqualTo , so then I can assert part of the message at least ?

Comment: Yes , you should try this .             StringAssert.Contains("your-text", exception.Message);